# Calendar week views block dates

Tags: 7, blocks, datetime

**Drupal 7.14 - Calendar Module 7.x-3.4**

Does anyone have an idea how to display the dates alongside the week days on the week views block?

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.

Comment: I found a solution while playing around with calendar module, I'll post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to copy calendar-week-overlap.tpl.php from calendar/theme to your custom Drupal theme and add the following lines:

**Add this code before html code - after line 30**

```
$start_date = date_format($view->date_info->min_date, 'U');
```

**After line 40 `<th class="calendar-agenda-hour">&nbsp;</th>` replace the following code**

```
 <?php foreach ($day_names as $cell): ?>
    <th class="<?php print $cell['class']; ?>" id="<?php print $cell['header_id']; ?>">
      <?php print $cell['data']; ?>
    </th>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**with this code**

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach ($day_names as $cell): ?>
    <th class="<?php print $cell['class']; ?>" id="<?php print $cell['header_id']; ?>">
      <?php print $cell['data']; ?>, <?php print date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+$i day", $start_date)); $i++ ?>
    </th>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```